# ArcGIS WFS Errors - Multiple Feature Class References

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, mxd, query-layer

I am trying to add WFS capabilities to an existing MXD, but it throws errors for multiple references to a Feature Class.

To work around this, I've tried two options: Creating database views and creating query layers.

Both of  which I've had successes and errors with.

Here is a code snippet of the logic I am using for the database view method:

```
whereclause = layer.definitionQuery
layername = layer.name
featureClass = os.path.basename(layer.dataSource)
vName = featureClass+"_view"
viewDef = "SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE {1}".format(featureClass,whereclause)
arcpy.CreateDatabaseView_management(input_database=sdepath, view_name=vName, view_definition=viewDef)
layer.replaceDataSource(sdepath,'SDE_WORKSPACE',vName)
```

When I run this logic in a script, I get an error saying that the view is not registered with the geodatabase.

I've tried to use the arcpy.RegisterWithGeodatabase_management() method but this throws an error saying views are not supported.

However, run I run the logic manually it automatically adds an additional step of creating a Query Layer when I try to replace the data source with the view.

I assumed this is what is fixing the issue so I went this route and tried this method of creating a query layer and deleting the old layer.

```
arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management(sdepath,vName,viewDef)
layerLoc = os.path.dirname(mxdpath)+'\\'+vName+".lyr" 
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(vName,layerLoc)
newlyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layerLoc)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(dataFrames[x],newlyr,'TOP')
del newlyr
arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(dataFrames[x]keys)
```

Now this seemed to solve the issue for the publishing error and worked on my end, but when I handed my script to someone to test, they said they could not open the newly generated MXD (could just be an arcMap issue).

I was wondering if this is a valid solution to this problem.

Would there be any problems for people who are using this service?

Any performance issues?

In my query layer method I am NOT creating a database view. It is a completely separate approach.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the error (which you didn't provide), and have wandered off into the weeds with an unnecessary task. Rather than asking for assistance with your solution, I  really think you should be focusing on the problem.

Comment: What is the WFS error?